# Google Universal Analytics - What should I upgrade my eCommerce tracking to?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I just upgraded my Google Analytics to Google Universal Analytics.

Should my eCommerce tracking change at all?

Script is below - left out some proprietary code that inserts the data, but I'm sure you get the gist.

```
<!-- google receipt begin -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',    
"", // order ID - required      
"", // affiliation or store name      
"", // total - required      
"", // tax      
"", // shipping      
"", // city      
"", // state or province      
"" // country    
]);          
// add item might be called for every item in the shopping cart
// where your ecommerce engine loops through each item in the cart and
// prints out _addItem for each
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
"", // order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction      
"", // SKU/code - required      
"", // product name      
"", // category or variation      
"", // unit price - required      
"" // quantity - required   
]);        
_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the analytics servers    
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
<!-- google receipt end -->
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs at the Universal Analytics Upgrade Center?

Comment: @Steven Yeah, haven't really found a section on eCommerce tracking. Maybe I haven't looked hard enough, however.

Comment: @Steven After looking at GA's new ecommerce tracking stuff...I'm still as confused as I went in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's documentation is 
[Ecommerce Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce).

The code should look like this:

```
// Create the tracker
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');

// Fire off a pageview
ga('send', 'pageview');

// Include the ecommerce plugin
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

// Initialize the transaction
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
             id: '1234abc',     // Transaction ID*
    affiliation: 'Tech Shirts', // Store Name
        revenue: '52.19',       // Total
       shipping: '10',          // Shipping
            tax: '3.22'         // Tax
});

// Add a few items
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
          id: '1234abc',            // Transaction ID*
         sku: 'TSHIRT-12A',         // Product SKU
        name: 'Analytics Wizard',   // Product Name*
    category: 'Men\'s Shirts',      // Product Category
       price: '12.99',              // Price
    quantity: '1'                   // Quantity
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
          id: '1234abc',            // Transaction ID*
         sku: 'TSHIRT-36B',         // Product SKU
        name: 'Best Developer',     // Product Name*
    category: 'Women\'s Shirts',    // Product Category
       price: '12.99',              // Price
    quantity: '2'                   // Quantity
});

// Send off the transaction
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

@MisterPhilip has a [nice blog post](http://misterphilip.com/universal-analytics/migration/ecommerce) on migrating your ecommerce tracking from Google Analytics to Universal Analytics.

Comment: That worked marvelously. I was having trouble because at the end of the current code I have the JS stuff and wasn't sure what to do with it.